# Ibis Python Help: ValueError: Multiple backends found

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, ibis

I am trying to convert a joined table to a python dataframe using Ibis. The two tables I am using are from bigquery and can convert them to dataframe easily. But when I join them and call the execute() method, it gives me the "ValueError: Multiple backends found" error.

Have searched multiple ways but none work. These two tables also don't have any overlapping column names.

```py
daily_join = visit_table.left_join(daily_table, 
                    [visit_table.date == daily_table.date ]).materialize()

daily = daily_join.limit(10)
daily_df = daily.execute()
```

Even if you can't guess what's happening here, could you at least tell when this Multiple Backend error occurs in Ibis?

Answer (score 0):

Are `visit_table` and `daily_table` both coming from BigQuery? Can you show how you obtain these tables? You should get each table from the same client (the object you get from calling `ibis.biquery.api.connect`) rather than getting each table from a separate client. This should solve your multiple backend problem.